# R Shiny: Updating Multiple Dependent Dropdown Menus with Leaflet Map Click

Tags: r, shiny, drop-down-menu, r-leaflet, selectinput

I have an interactive map rendered with `leaflet` in a `shiny` dashboard in `R`. The dashboard also contains two dropdown menus created with `selectizeInput`, where the options available in the second dropdown depend on the selection in the first dropdown. In the toy example below, the second dropdown presents a list of cities, which depends on the country selected in the first dropdown.

I would like to specify the selections in these two dropdown menus by clicking on the city in the map. In the code below, this works once you have chosen a country. For example, if I select "Australia" from the first dropdown and then click on Australian cities in the map, the selected city in the second dropdown updates correctly. However, if I then click on a city in New Zealand, "Auckland" (the first city in the New Zealand list) is selected in the city dropdown regardless of which New Zealand city I actually clicked on. Subsequent clicks on cities in New Zealand then work correctly.

How can I get the city dropdown to update correctly the first time I click on a city in a different country to that currently selected in the country dropdown?

Note: This is only intended as a simple, reproducible example of the functionality that I require.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

cities <- data.frame(country = c(rep('Australia',5),rep('New Zealand',3)),
                     city = c("Adelaide", "Brisbane", "Melbourne", "Perth", "Sydney", "Auckland", "Christchurch", "Wellington"),
                     lat = c(-34.9329, -27.469, -37.8142, -31.9527, -33.868, -36.85, -43.53, -41.2889),
                     long = c(138.5998, 153.0235, 144.9632, 115.8605, 151.21, 174.7833, 172.6203, 174.7772))


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width=12, leafletOutput("map"))),
  fluidRow(
    column(width=4, 
           selectizeInput(inputId = "countrySelected",label = "Country", choices = cities$country),
           uiOutput("citySelectedUI"))
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # THE MAP:
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(cities) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng=152, lat=-36, zoom=4) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, radius=4, label=~city) 
  })
  
  # THE CITIES DROPDOWN (CONDITIONAL ON SELECTED COUNTRY)
  output$citySelectedUI <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("citySelected", "City", choices=cities$city[cities$country==input$countrySelected])
  })
  
  # NOT WORKING CORRECTLY: Clicking city on map should update country and city selected 
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$map_marker_click)){
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, "countrySelected", 
        selected = cities$country[(cities$lat==input$map_marker_click$lat)&(cities$long==input$map_marker_click$lng)])
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, "citySelected", 
        selected = cities$city[(cities$lat==input$map_marker_click$lat)&(cities$long==input$map_marker_click$lng)])
    }
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  # WORKING CORRECTLY: Clicking city on map should update country and city selected 
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    if(!is.null(input$map_marker_click)){
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, "countrySelected", 
        selected = cities$country[(cities$lat==input$map_marker_click$lat)&(cities$long==input$map_marker_click$lng)])
    }
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$map_marker_click)){
      req(input$countrySelected)
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, "citySelected", 
        selected = cities$city[(cities$lat==input$map_marker_click$lat)&(cities$long==input$map_marker_click$lng)])
    }
    
  })
```